# warning not treated as error with -Wall & -Werror on

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

Here is the content of source file get.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  //int i = 0;
  char b[10];
  gets(b);
  puts(b);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile it with these command

> ```
> gcc -o get get.c -Wall -Werror
> ```

The output is

> ```
> /tmp/ccYEWZvx.o: In function `main':
> get.c:(.text+0x10): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
> ```

But when change the code to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int i = 0; // **this line just be uncommented**
  char b[10];
  gets(b);
  puts(b);
  return 0;
}
```

Using the same command, the output is

> ```
> cc1: warnings being treated as errors  
> get.c: In function 'main':  
> get.c:4: error: unused variable 'i'
> ```

So, why this unused variable warning be treated as error, while the use of `gets()` not?

Comment: The warning about `gets` appears to be issued by the linker, not by the compiler.

Comment: Specifically, `gets` is fundamentally insecure and is *deprecated* in C11.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `gets()` warning is being issued by the linker *not* the compiler, so the compiler settings do not apply.

Only the linker is able to determine that the symbol is resolved with the standard library `gets()` rather than some other implementation with the same name.

To instruct the linker to treat warnings as errors you need to pass it the `--fatal-warnings` option.  In turn when not invoking the linker directly, options are passed to the linker by gcc using the `-Wl` option in a comma separated list:

```
gcc -o get get.c -Wall -Werror -Wl,--fatal-warnings
```

Note that the [GNU linker](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.28/ld/index.html) is documented separately from the compiler, as part of [binutils](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.28/).  The linker options are described [here](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.28/ld/Options.html).

Comment: Then, can I treat linker warnings as errors?@Clifford

Comment: The compiler could do the warning about `gets`, but it chooses not to. The fact that it's undefined behaviour for the user to call their own function `gets` gives the compiler this freedom

Comment: @M.M : It is not the compiler that chose not to, rather then compiler implementer (save us from the AI compiler!).  All standard library symbols are _reserved_ in the sense they they must have external linkage - not that they may not be overridden. 
If one took the trouble to _deliberately_ do that, it might be annoying to get a warning.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the output from the first example, it says the "error" is in an *object file*, which means it is generated by the linker.

The second error is generated by the compiler, which means there is no object file being generated and so the linker will not be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

`-Werror` make all warnings as errors, to print only security warnings you can use: `-Wformat -Wformat-security` 
You can read warnings options here https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

The compiler abort the compilation if an error is occurred, instead it continue the compilation if there are one or more warnings.