# Azure DevOps pipeline: Can I turn all warnings into errors?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

There are many reasons why Azure DevOps (ADS) pipelines may raise warnings but continue execution (for [example due to bad task design](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/14786)). As pipelines are often part of an automated workflow (e.g. nightly builds, pull request validation builds), the pipeline result page will not be looked at by a human in most cases. As a result, those warnings may be left unnoticed or ignored for a very long time.

To make sure that these warnings are taken care of, I would like to make them fail the pipeline, similar to the [`--fatal-warnings`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44753838/12932497) flag commonly used in compilers.

I tried searching the [official docmentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/?view=azure-pipelines), Microsoft's [issue tracker on pipeline tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues?q=is%3Aissue+fatal+warning) and the internet for similar flags, but I could not find anything useful.

Do you have any idea how to make warnings in ADS pipelines harder to miss and ignore?